# why am I getting previous django project's css instead of current django project?

Tags: css, django

I made static directory inside my app and kept my css folder inside static with the name style.css. I set the css link as :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
```

I think all the path is correct but it shows the previous project's css. why this is happening?

Comment: This is possibly due to the caching of the browser. Hard refreshing should resolve this.

Comment: Delete your browsing history , it might helping deleted cached content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic problem when developing multiple sites locally using the same resource names. Your browser has cached the contents of the file so it doesn't attempt to download the file again when the page loads. Usually this is a good thing as it makes your pages load faster, however in this case it's picking up a stale cached filed.

To fix this you'll need to perform a hard refresh, on Windows this is done by pressing Ctrl+Shift+R. If you have the Chrome developer tools open you can press and hold the refresh icon and it will show you the different refresh options.